# How to invest in tax liens?

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies, investment-property

I'm looking for some tips about investing in tax liens. How can I maximize profits? How much money do I need to invest in tax liens?

Comment: https://www.biggerpockets.com/blog/2013-02-11-tax-liens - 

https://www.biggerpockets.com/forums/70/topics/343700-tax-lien-books

Answer (score 3):

> How can I maximize profits? How much money do I need to invest in tax liens?

The fact that you are asking this questions means you are not ready for such investments. These are very risky and time consuming investments. [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/061313/investing-property-tax-liens.asp) has a good article on this.